# Question on how a matrix is calculated from an example

Tags: matrices

I have the following laplacian matrix given to me in a textbook.

[image]

In the textbook, the matrix calculation is always done from the 3 x 3 matrix (the methods I learnt makes me cut the matrix further into a 2 x 2 matrix).

How are the 3 x 3 matrix being calculated?

Comment: I don't believe you. I simply don't. The textbook, I am 100% sure of it, tells you how to calculate the detrminant of a $n\times n$ matrix. There is no way a textbook would only tell you how to calculate a $3\times 3$ determinant and then give you a task to do it for a $4\times 4$ one.

Comment: @5xum: That might be a misunderstanding -- the question doesn't say that the textbook only tells you how to calculate a $3\times3$ matrix -- it says that "in the textbook the matrix calculation is always done **from** the $3\times3$ matrix" -- I took that to mean that it's done as shown here, using $3\times3$ matrices to calculate the determinant of a $4\times4$ matrix.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean when you write, "is always done from the $3\times 3$ matrix." Do you mean that once the problem is reduced to solving only $3\times 3$ determinants, the rest of the calculation is all algebraic expressions involving only numbers (like the second line of equations in your example)? If you had to calculate the determinant of the $4\times 4$ matrix, how would you write the calculation? (EDIT: Your comment on another answer explains this; it might be good to edit that explanation into the question itself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider
$$
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
 3 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 &  3 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 &  3
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The $2\times 2$ matrices produced by eliminating the first row and one column
have the determinants
$$
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -1 \\
-1 &  3
\end{pmatrix} = 8,
\quad \det
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 \\
-1 &  3
\end{pmatrix} = -4,
\quad  \text{and}\quad  \det
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &  3 \\
-1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} = 4.
$$
That is how the values $8$, $-4$, and $4$ are derived in the equation
$$
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
 3 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 &  3 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 &  3
\end{pmatrix}
= 3 \times 8 - (-1) \times (-4) + (-1) \times 4.
$$
You can see the right-hand side of this equation 
on the second line of equations in the book's calculation of the determinant.

For
$$
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -1 \\
 0 &  3 & -1 \\
 0 & -1 &  3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
the first $2\times 2$ matrix (eliminating the first row and first column) has
$$
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -1 \\
-1 &  3
\end{pmatrix} = 8
$$
(the same as in the previous $3\times 3$ calculation), but the other
$2\times 2$ matrices that result by eliminating the first row both
have all zeros in the first column and therefore have determinant zero.
So the determinant of this $3\times 3$ matrix is
$$
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -1 \\
 0 &  3 & -1 \\
 0 & -1 &  3
\end{pmatrix}
 = (-1) \times 8,
$$
and again you can see the right-hand side of this equation
on the second line of equations in the book.

In other words, the book *is* cutting the $3\times 3$ matrices further
into $2\times 2$ matrices in order to compute the $3\times 3$ determinants;
the difference between this style of exposition and others you may have seen
is that only the values of the $2\times 2$ determinants are written in the
next step, rather than displaying all the $2\times 2$ matrices explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The top left entry of the large matrix is written down (the first "2" in your expression); its row and column are temporarily struck out, and the remaining $3 \times 3$ matrix is written inside a "det".

Then the next entry to the right  (a $-1$) is *negated* and written down (in your case, the implicit "1" just ebfore the second "det"); its row and column are temporarily struck out, and the remaining $3 \times 3$ determinant written down.

The last two entries in the first row have the same process applied: the next one left as is, the last one negated. Since they're both zeroes, however, those terms end up zero and have not been written down.

Comment: Sorry I should've made it a bit more clearer.
I do understand how the determinant matrices are created but I'm unsure how it goes from that matrix into: 2(3 x 8 - (-1) x 5 + (-1) x 4) without cutting down into a 2 x 2 matrix